# Bypass Samsung Knox factory reset protection

Tags: adb, security, samsung-knox

I have an Android device supplied by my government for students and secured by Samsung Knox. However & unfortunately, I forgot the security pattern of the device and I want to hard reset it to access it again. But Knox prevents factory reset by all the ways :/

I have tried entering the pattern in a wrong way 20+ times but it still refuses to achieve a factory reset. I have also tried booting into Android recovery but the factory reset option says `MDM disallows factory reset`.

Also Google's Find My Device can't even detect the device so I can't reset it using Google's Find My Device.
And developer options are disabled by Knox too so I can't do it using `adb`

I know that I have made it complex but its the truth and I was wondering if someone knows any way or PC tool to hard reset without USB debugging, or a PC tool that can enable USB debugging.

I don't want to flash ROMs because they will erase Knox which I shouldn't erase :/

Comment: you misunderstand what factory reset protection does. even after successful factory reset or flashing (official) rom you won't be able to by-pass factory reset protection. bootloader is locked and device is bonded to samsung account and it's the only (official) way to use Find My Mobile

Comment: @alecxs I don't need to hack my device and I want it to continue entering the Knox organization. But I just want to hard reset because I forgot the pattern

Comment: you need to remember your samsung account and login to https://findmymobile.samsung.com there you can set temporary screen lock pattern or factory reset