# How to factory reset a SAMSUNG tablet using Odin without tripping KNOX

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, factory-reset, odin, samsung-knox

Almost all of the questions I've asked here are related to the same topic, which is: I've forgot my unlock screen pattern and I am unable to factory reset my tablet to gain access to the tablet again (I don't need the data, I just need to access my tablet).

Here was my first question: [Bypass Samsung Knox factory reset protection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221395/bypass-samsung-knox-factory-reset-protection) - and there I've mentioned that SAMSUNG Knox prevents factory resetting the device by all the ways possible (also it disables USB debugging by all the ways possible).

So another idea came to my mind, that idea is to flash an `ADB enable` file on the tablet so I can perform a factory reset through `adb`, but I was worried if this would trip the KNOX 0x0 counter to 0x1 or no, so I've asked about it here [Will flashing "ADB enable" trigger Knox warranty bit?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221868/will-flashing-adb-enable-trigger-knox-warranty-bit) and it was answered that it would trip KNOX :/

So I was wondering if its possible to perform a factory reset using ODIN without modifying the `boot.img` as this will trip KNOX I guess.

I am a student and I received this tablet from my school and I shouldn't trip KNOX because they manage it through the KNOX products, also I shouldn't lose the warranty of it.

The nearest Samsung service center to me is very far (really far).

I wish there could be a way to achieve a factory reset :/

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT**: The guys on Reddit say that flashing the official ROM shouldn't trip the KNOX counter here:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/samsung/comments/69mxbj/can_i_flash_a_official_samsung_firmware_via_odin/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS9/comments/997utz/flash_an_official_rom_with_odin_without_tripping/

and on SamMobile.com forums:

- https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/28285-Does-flashing-stock-firmware-to-a-different-region-trip-Knox?p=125996&viewfull=1#post125996
- https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/44838-S8-does-flashing-different-CSC-trip-knox?p=218882&viewfull=1#post218882
- https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/38344-Tripped-Knox-using-stock-firmware-what-did-i-do-wrong?p=191518&viewfull=1#post191518

can someone *experienced* confirm this? I would be in a serious trouble if I tripped the KNOX counter and I will have to pay a high fine.

**EDIT**: Also, if flashing the official ROM from SamMobile.com doesn't trip KNOX and I flashed it, will it remove the auto enrollment setup by my school (Knox Mobile Enrollment)?